# Encode string to 34 byte hex for SQLite password

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, encryption, windows-phone

I'm trying to use SQLite on Windows Phone using csharp-sqlite. I've got an existing encrypted database and need to pass the password in but it doesn't work when passing the string. I found [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/issues/detail?id=76&can=1&q=password) but it says that I need to pass a 32 byte hex key but how do I convert my existing string into a 34 byte hex key?

Thanks

As asked in comments, here's the current code which works fine with the database if the database is not encrypted and I remove the "Password" part. As soon as it's encrypted, there seems to be an error thrown (such as Table X not existing even though it does as the same SQL statement works when there's no encryption) and I think I've debugged it down to the fact that the library I'm using can't seem to accept string passwords and requires a hexkey.

```
 using (var conn = new SqliteConnection("data source=file:db.db3,Password=mypwd"))
 {
 }
```

I've tried various combinations of the connectionstring including adding Version=3 and using semi-colons instead of commas.

Comment: SQLite doesn't take passwords, so presumably you mean SqlCipher.  And if you give SqlCipher a password that is other than 32 hex bytes it will hash it into the appropriate 32-byte key.

Comment: Thanks, that seems right but how do I use the SqlCipher? I've created a new instance of it but not sure where I enter my existing string.

Comment: Post your current code?

Comment: SqlCipher vs SQLite is just a matter of which static library you use.  SqlCipher is a modified version of SQLite.  (Note that it's quite possible to use SQLite and think you're getting encryption when you're not.  The only sure-fire way to test is to access the DB without using a key and see if you can read it.)

Comment: @DuncanJones I've posted the code to open the connection. This works fine on unencrypted databases. Thanks.

Comment: @HotLicks I can access the DB if I remove the encryption on the database, so it seems it's passing the password that's the problem. I've added a bit more info in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Under the covers, you enable encryption on a SqlCipher database by issuing a "PRAGMA REKEY <newkey>", and you open an already-encrypted DB by issuing "PRAGMA KEY <key>" immediately after opening.  Dunno how your C# libraries may be translating the above operations into PRAGMAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this post](http://developmobi.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/encryption-for-sqlite-and-windows-phone.html), it's not possible to use System.Data.SQLite encryption with the csharp-sqlite library.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SqlCipher but the [sample code on their website](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-ado) does not use a password integrated into the connection string, but set on the connection afterwards:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=sqlcipher.db;Pooling=false;";
((SQLiteConnection)conn).SetPassword("secret");
conn.Open();
```

If assigning the password through the connection string is possible, you may want to try a semicolon instead of a comma to separate the values.

Comment: *SQLite doesn't have built-in encryption.*  There is, in addition to the open-source SqlCipher, a proprietary [SQLite Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html), which I suppose may be what you're using.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've been given the System.Data.SQLite library on the PC that I've been using as a wrapper. I can't change it as that's what I've been asked to use on the PC version. I encrypted using the method shown here http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/130.aspx

Comment: @NewCode sorry I did not understand that initially. The example from your link also uses semicolons by the way to split the ConnectionString parts.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis That's no problem, thanks for trying. I tried using semicolons but unfortunately that didn't work either :(